# Can a .net web app be registered as mobile\native client platfrom in Azure APP registrations?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a .net 4.5 web applicated hosted on web servers.
I want to implement Azure AD for authentication to my application.
I want to register my app in Azure APP registartion.
Here while registering If I register my app as WEB APP platform, it is not treated as public client and I am forced to use ConfidentialclientAPP to get token. IS there a way i can use publicclientapplication to get token interactively for the same app. I am being thrown with client secret is needed.

Answer (score 0):

To identify your application as a public client application:

1. ***Go to Azure portal ->select your app -> App registrations, and then select  Authentication***
2. ***In  Advanced settings - >  Allow public client flows ->  Enabled the following mobile and desktop flows and click save.***

[image]

MSAL allows apps to acquire tokens silently and interactively.You can get tokens via protocol authentication process, you need to request

- Get an authorization code.
- Exchange the code for a token.

```
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<CLIENT_ID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=<ENCODED_REDIRECT_URI>
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&state=12345r code here`
```

To get access and refresh token:

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=<CLIENT_ID>
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
&redirect_uri=<ENCODED_REDIRECT_URI>
&grant_type=authorization_code
```

***Reference:***

- [Acquire a token to call a web API (mobile apps) - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-mobile-acquire-token)
- [Register mobile apps that call web APIs - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-mobile-app-registration)